# match and get count of 2 common field values in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There are 2 students: a and b. a likes subjects chem,phy,bio and b likes phy,math,bio.They have a workshop every week and I would like to know count of both their subjects according to the workshop_attended in desc order.

currently I am using this query to get subjects he likes based on workshop attended:

```
MATCH (s:student{id:"1",name:"a"} )-[:workshop_attended]-(b:workshop)-[y:subject_likes]-(c:subjects)  RETURN c,count(c) as total
```

Btw,is the above query correct w.r.t count and subjects?

Now I would like to know how many common subjects they have liked together by attending the workshops and also count of each of those subjects.How can I do it .I tried this but I always got 0 rows.

```
MATCH (s:student{id:"1",name:"a"} )-[:workshop_attended]-(b:workshop)-[y:subject_likes]-(c:subjects),
 (s2:student{id:"2",name:”b"} )-[:workshop_attended]-(b2:workshop)-[y2:subject_likes]-(c:subjects)

  RETURN c,count(c) as total
```

Also I tried:

```
MATCH (s:student{id:"1",name:"a"} )-[:workshop_attended]-(b:workshop)-[y:subject_likes]-(c:subjects),
 (s2:student{id:"2",name:”b"} )-[:workshop_attended]-(b2:workshop)-[y2:subject_likes]-(l:subjects)

  RETURN c,count(c),l,count(l) as total
```

Even that is wrong also I get more rows for some reason .I really appreciate any help.

Comment: can you plz share your graph (or some part of it) via http://console.neo4j.org?

Comment: and what you expect to see.

Comment: try to use **two match statements**, otherwise you have relationships that are already part of your path and will not be visited again.

Comment: is it possible to group workshops together and find which student has attended eg: workshop:id=1 has student=1,2,3,4,5 and workshop 2 has 3,5,6,7,8.Basically how can I group workshop ids and get list of users_id.I used collect on both workshop and ids .BUt I guess its not looking like the way I want it.How can I do it?